# mongoDB chat system database structure

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

> i am trying to create group chat system using mongoDB but in mongoose object type is supported how can i create model like this(inserting image below)? and also query this data? i've tried to create schema but didnt work

[sample of model (dummy)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCwUX.png)

Answer (score 0):

`const chatSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ users: Array, texts:[{ user: String, text: String, time: Date, }] });`

Try this schema. Users who will be in group chat will added in `users` field. The text will have author(`user`), text(`text`) and date(`time`).